# Use JS script on Django html?

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

When using my js script in html, I get an error: the file was not found, although the file is in the directory. Help me to understand. Thanks!

I have next structure of project:

```
---- app
-------- urls.py
-------- settings.py
-------- wsgi.py
---- health_app
-------- urls.py
-------- templates
------------- scripts
------------------ myscript.js
------------- index.html
```

I can use myscript.js in my app health_app.

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/scripts/myscript.js"></script>
```

console error:

```
Not Found: /health_app/templates/scripts/myscript.js
[18/Oct/2022 07:34:52] "GET /health_app/templates/scripts/myscript.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2303
```

Comment: Are you aware of managing static files in django?

Answer (score 2):

you should add static file in django settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#Location of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

and in html file, on top of file

```
{% load static %}
```

after that when you want to load a JS file, your script should be is static folder

```
<script src="{% static 'path_to_the_script' %}"></script>
```

and I suggest to you read more about [Django static file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/)